# 指定した期間内のデータ抽出方法について: No matching signature for operator BETWEEN for argument types: TIMESTAMP, DATE, DATE

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

### やりたいこと

ビッグクエリのデータテーブルに対し、特定のカラム（タイムスタンプ型）を指定して任意の期間内のデータのみ抽出したい。

### 抽出条件

・satei_date　が　2か月以内

### 現状のエラー

以下の通りクエリを記載しておりますが、エラーが出る状況です。
原因と修正方法についてご教示いただけますと幸いです。

#### クエリ

```
WHERE satei_date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE() and DATE(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL -2 MONTH)
```

#### エラーコード

```
No matching signature for operator BETWEEN for argument types: TIMESTAMP, DATE, DATE. Supported signature: (ANY) BETWEEN (ANY) AND (ANY)
```

Answer (score 1):

TIMESTAMP 型と DATE型を比較しようとしてエラーが発生してます。
ご利用のデータベースが何か不明ですが、CURRENT_DATE() 等で返される値を TIMESTANP 型に変換する関数を使えばいいかと思います。